# Name for device acting like a circulator but for higher currents

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, identification, components

I believe for getting further in [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/658140/334691) post, I am looking for an electrical component/device that acts like an [RF circulator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulator)
but instead of passing on radio waves between an antenna and a transmitter/teceiver, I need said device to pass on about 100W 12V.

I need to use it (as described in the linked post) to supply 12V ~1A from a UPS to a USB controller, which can also accept 5-20V 5A power from "outside" and provide it to the UPS (on the same terminals.) The USB controller is meant for connecting directly to a battery via its terminal but I could maybe also inject the power somewhere else on the board.

What I think I must prevent, is creating a circular power flow from UPS input to UPS output.

The UPS also senses the input so I need the input line to be below 5V when no outside power is connected.

EDIT:
Circle I'm trying to avoid:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJGymA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Connections I need (I think):

As you can see, when running on battery power (or 12VDC from the wall) the USB-PD controller should get 12V through the UPS.

When you connect a power supply via USB-C the power should go into the UPS input, so it can charge the batteries and provide power and power status to the system.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCOdUS.png)</sup>

Comment: Please draw a diagram of your system with the circuit tool

Comment: It sounds like what you're looking for is a diode...

Comment: If I were to use 3 diodes, Power still could "go in a circle". I need the device to have (at least 3 Poles) and Pole 1 can send to pole 2, and pole 3 can send to pole 1. nothing more.

Comment: @VoltageSpike I have edited the original question to include schematics.

Comment: What is the USB PD board? Can it source an sink current? It's likely that it could only do one or the other

Comment: @VoltageSpike The USB-PD board is DRP (Dual-Role-Power) compliant. You can find a link to it in the linked post of mine.

Answer (score 0):

Compliant USB-PD power supplies act as ideal diodes anyway. They have built-in reverse current protection. So the good news is that you don't have to do anything. The USB-PD boards will not back-feed the energy to the power source.

Comment: sadly, this is not my concern. My problem is that I would probably backfeed (or at least have a voltage) from UPS output to UPS input, when *not* charging via type-C. I will include another "schematic", lining out better, what I mean.